# ReactJS: Conditional rendering of child components depending on if userData is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I feel like I'm doing something wrong. When a user logs in to our application, redux is updated with the response from the server.

A lot of components depend on this logged-in state.

We pass the `currentUser` object through props to all of our child components. To make sure the object is there we have a check:

```
{isEmpty(currentUser) ? <Loading /> : <PersonalDashboard currentUser={this.props.currentUser} />}
```

We do this so that the `<PersonalDashboard />` will have the data it needs. Otherwise we risk sending in a empty object.

Now, alternatively, I have seen using `connect()` to check the store, but this also seems overly cumbersome as I want to keep the child components as simple as possible.

Is this the right way to go about handling currentUser? Or is there an alternative way to check for appropriate data and then match that to appropriate component rendering?

Example:

```
<Routes currentUser={this.props.currentUser} />

const mapStateToProps = ({ session }) => {
 return {
   currentUser: session.user // this comes from our session reducer
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes);
```

between `<Routes>` and `<Routes />`

```
<Route path="/personal" component={PersonalDashboard} currentUser={this.props.currentUser} />
```

inside `<PersonalDashboard /> render() {`

```
{isEmpty(this.props.currentUser) ? <Loading /> : <PersonalAccount currentUser={this.props.currentUser} />}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux attempts to make state mutations predictable by imposing certain restrictions on how and when updates can happen. One of the most important idea is that the  state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within a single store.

So in your case you could think to use a component which get user login information from the store and share its state with other components using react render props.
More infos and examples here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: I like what you are saying, could you help me with an example: `<PersonalDashboard render={display => <Loading />} />` and then inside `<PersonalDashboard />`  inside return, how do I determine if it should show <Loading /> or the current render?